# What is the capacitor charging equation for this circuit

Tags: capacitor, transient

[image]

The capacitor is charged to 20 V at time=0. Now it is connected to a battery of 80 V. What will be the charging equation. If the terminal are reversed it will be the discharging of capacitor-charging of capacitor as the voltage reaches zero across the capacitor and becomes negative. In this case I think capacitor start charging from 20 V till it reaches 80 V, but I can't form the equation for it.

Comment: Schematic shows 40 V. Text says 80 V. Which is it?

Comment: For homework questions we expect you to make a substantial effort to solve the question yourself. Show us all of your work, then ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a capacitor that is pre-charged to 20 volts is then connected via a series resistor to a (say) 50 volt source, you can think of this problem as a fully discharged capacitor connected to a 30 volt source via the resistor. I think you indicate that you know how to solve that.

So, when you have solved for \$V_C\$, add a DC voltage of 20 volts to that equation.